# Why do my photos look less punchy in Laptop than camera when both are set to sRGB color space? Why is there a change in photos at all?

Tags: canon, post-processing, digital, shooting-technique, color-spaces

I use canon m50 set to RAW to click pictures, they look good on the LCD of the camera but when imported to laptop (Predator Helios 300), it looks bland and less punchy. Even though the reality was punchy. How do I prevent this from happening and get the same results on my laptop that I see on camera? Both are operating in sRGB color space and I've used all the popular photo viewers and editors, both give the same bad results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the software that came with your camera (Digital Photo Pro). OEM software can read the raw image exif and apply exactly the same edits that the camera applies to the jpegs it generates. 3rd party software can't do that; DPP does it by default.

Or just set the camera to record jpegs if it generates images you like... if you get the exposure right, and the picture style settings aren't extreme, there's very few negatives to recording jpegs in most situations. And most photographers spend most of their editing time/processing just to get the image up to jpeg level... or they have default edits automatically applied, which is about the same as just recording jpegs.

Or set the camera to record raw+jpeg; then you have a backup raw copy and a processed jpeg to use.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention RAW let me clarify: RAW files are not images.

What you see on the camera screen is preview of the images i.e. already "edited" photo. In most of the cases desktop software display shortly the preview image and then render the RAW file and display it. So you need to add some corrections, do some edit and you will have better looking image.

Another point is to calibrate your laptop screen to get precise colours. And trust it, not the camera screen.

sRGB colour space just define "which colours" can be displayed on the devices and is not directly (much) related to how your image looks like.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick help, how do I calibrate display to get precise colors? Any tips or youtube links?

Comment: @Mohd.FarhanHassan, you need calibration device/hardware (and accomplished software).

Comment: If you are not printing I would not worry about precise color calibration; because the images will look different on every screen/device. Just make sure there's not a big WB shift/issue... Windows 10 & 11 has built in software to help you to do that.

Comment: you can use a DSLR to calibrate your monitor. just set it on cloudy WB to target 6500. shoot a on-screen step wedge and measure the diff between R,G and B on each step. Adjust the controls until R, G, and B match when re-shot with the same camera. Takes about 5 tries and 30 mins, or you can buy something to do all that knob-twiddling for you, but a DSLR is a calibrated color sensor; millions of them in fact.